# Write to a file in Python that's actually a variable?

Tags: python, file, variables

I have a package I'm using for my research that has a class with a method that writes some information but only writes that information to a file (i.e., the method takes a file object as an argument and as its only argument).  However, I need that particular information in my code, not in a file.

My current solution is to have the method write the information to a file like it wants to do and then later open that file and use basic I/O functions to read in the information.

I am wondering, though, is there a way to trick the method into thinking it's writing to a file when it's actually writing to a variable or a list or something?  In other words, is there a way I can make a file object that actually points to a variable/list/array/whatever  in the code and not to an actual file?

current:

```
with open('file.txt','w') as f:
    method.write_info(f)

with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    info = f.readlines()
```

what I want (more or less; I'm just using the same open file syntax as I'm familiar with):

```
with open(<some sort of variable>) as var_file:
    method.write_info(var_file)

#Then do whatever I want with the information
print <some sort of variable>
```

Note: I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: Maybe make a new class that inherit your original class that contains that function, and rewrite/override that function specifically (replace the write to file part to write to a variable) in your new class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [StringIO object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) as an in-memory buffer that works like a file.

Comment: As OP uses Python2, he could also use a BytesIO if he does not want to end with a unicode string.

Answer (score 1):

Actually any object that implements the part of the `file` api used by `write_info()` will work. Assuming `write_info()` only uses `file.write()`, the following would do:

```
class PseudoFile(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = []

    def write(self, value):
        self.content.append(value)

    def __str__(self):
        return "".join(map(str, self.content))

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)


f = PseudoFile()
method.write_info(f)
print f
```